# How to select last entry for one distinct pairing of two columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select the last row in `mytable` for a given pair of columns in Oracle v11.2:

```
id    type     timestamp     raw_value     normal_value
--    ----     ---------     ---------     ------------
1     3        3pm 3-Jun     "Jon"         "Jonathan"
1     3        5pm 3-Jun     "Jonathan"    "Jonathan"
1     3        2pm 4-Jun     "John"        "Jonathan"
1     3        8pm 6-Jun     "Bob"         "Robert"
1     5        6pm 3-Jun     "NYC"         "New York City"
1     5        7pm 5-Jun     "N.Y.C."      "New York City"
4     8        1pm 1-Jun     "IBM"         "International Business Machines"
4     8        5pm 8-Jun     "I.B.M."      "International Business Machines"
```

I'm thinking the query would be something like this:

```
SELECT raw_value, normal_value, MAX(timestamp)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE id = 1 and type = 3
  GROUP BY id, type
```

For the above, this should give me:

> "Bob", "Robert", 8pm 6-Jun

I do not actually need the `timestamp` in my answer, but only need it to select the matching row for the given `id` and `type` whose `timestamp` is greatest.

Will my approach work in Oracle v11.2, and if so, is there a way to omit `timestamp` from the selected columns since I don't actually need its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `row_number()` function:

```
select raw_value, normal_value, timestamp
from (select myt.*, ROW_NUMBER() over
           (partition by id, type order by timestamp desc)
      as seqnum
      from mytable myt
     ) tmp
where seqnum = 1
and id = 1 and type = 3;
```

`row_number()` is an analytic function (aka window function) that assigns sequential numbers to rows.  Every group defined by `id, type` gets its own numbers.  The first row is the one with the most recent timestamp (`order by timestamp desc`).  The outer `select` chooses this row in the `where` clause.

In the case of ties, this version returns only one row.  To get all the rows, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Does the `timestamp` need to be selected in the outer select for this to work?  I ask since I don't actually need the value once I get the last entry.

Comment: @WilliamKF . . . Not at all.  It is in your sample results.

Comment: Do the `seqnum`(s) get generated before or after the where clause?  In other words, if my where clause filters out the first sorted match, will there be no rows left with `seqnum` of value 1 or will the numbering of rows be done after applying the where clause?

Comment: @WilliamKF . . . Because the `row_number()` is in a subquery and the `where` is in the outer query, the `where` does not affect it.  If they were at the same level, then the `where` would affect it (but then again, it could not reference `seqnum`).

Comment: So, I take your answer to mean that I should add a where clause to the inner query to ensure in the outer query that seqnum = 1 is available, correct?

Comment: @WilliamKF . . . It actually doesn't make a difference.  The `where` clause is on the same columns as the `partition` statement uses.  If there were no `partition` statement, then you would need to put the `where` clause in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT m1.raw_value, m1.normal_value
FROM mytable m1
WHERE id = 1 and type = 3 and timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM mytable m2
    WHERE m1.id = m2.id and m1.type = m2.type
    GROUP BY m2.id, m2.type
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the most recent timestamp using the Oracle analytic RANK function like this:

```
SELECT
  raw_value,
  normal_value,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as TimestampRank
FROM myTable
```

This will set the `TimestampRank` column with value 1 for the row with the highest timestamp. If there's a tie for the highest timestamp, all rows with the highest timestamp with have `TimestampRank` set to 1.

To get just the `"Bob", "Robert"`, surround the query above with an outer query that selects just those columns and filters for `TimestampRank = 1`:

```
SELECT raw_value, normal_value
FROM (
  SELECT
    raw_value,
    normal_value,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as TimestampRank
  FROM myTable
)
WHERE TimestampRank = 1
```

Note again that if there's a tie for the highest timestamp, all rows with that value will be returned. If you always want one row regardless of ties, use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()` in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select max(raw_value ) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp),
max(normal_value ) keep (dense_rank last order by timestamp)
from mytable
WHERE id = 1 and type = 3
```